# HTML5 Lives are not updating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Maze that you go through with your mouse and I have a function for lives which is

```
var life = 3;
function lives(){
life --;
}
```

the way I am displaying this lives is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<div id='hp'>" + "Lives: " + life + "</div>");
</script>
```

I am calling the function with these blocks but they aren't updating the lives Help!
`<img id="a1" src="blackpixel.png" onMouseOver="lives()"/>`

Comment: when do you call the `document.write` line ? the display won't refresh unless you make it to do so.

Comment: Updated it to show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onmouseover` only update the value of variable `lives`, but you do not update the display of Lives. You can add this line after `line --;`:

```
document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = 'Lives: ' + life;
```

Comment: my current script is now <script type="text/javascript">
 var life = 3;
 function lives(){
  document.getElementById('hp').innerHTML = "Lives: " + life;
   life --;
 }
</script>
 and it dosnt work =\ coulld it be because the variable is outside the function?